# Combined flair not adding "web app" site?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, flair, combined-flair

I'm using the combined flair on my blog. I added it when I had the requirements in only SO and SU. Now I got 200-some rep on webapps.SE sometime yesterday but the combined flair has not been updated on my accounts or on my blog.

Is there latency and I just need to wait? Is webapps.SE not included?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, Stack Exchange reputation is not updated until the end of the day. So I guess the flair follow the same way.

Eventually you can try to synchronise it from your Stack Exchange account once a day by clicking the *Sync with oldest profile* located beneath your About Me.

Or you would just have to wait a little.

Comment: Ok. This is what I thought. But I also thought I got the rep more than 24 hours ago, and both getting the rep, and NOW are mid-day for me, so I wasn't sure how they were measuring their days. Maybe I'm just mistaken, I'll try patience still for now.

Comment: @josmh, your reputation history on WebApps shows that you hit 200 about 10 hours ago, if I read it right.

Comment: Oh really? You're right. My mistake. Thanks.

Comment: @josmh Your Stack Exchange profile also includes a statement of when it was last synced, so you can also check that to compare the time of sync with the 10 hour mark mmyers pointed out.